# React Three Fiber Canvas not resizing to size of parent when modal is opened

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, antd, web3js, react-three-fiber

I am trying to use a `Canvas` from `react-three-fiber` inside a modal. I use the `Canvas` throughout my application and it works fine. However, when inside the modal it does not resize to the `width` and `height` of its parent element, making it extremely tiny. If I set a `min-width` and `min-height` on the `.canvas` html element it appears with the right dimensions but is extremely fuzzy. In addition whenever I scroll the `Canvas` pops to the correct dimensions and is not fuzzy. What is going on here and how can I fix it/ work around it? I want to be able to have a `Canvas` inside a modal.

Here is a stripped down version of the code I am working with:

```
<Modal visible={props.isOpen}>
    <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px'}}>
        <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 1] }}>
            <spotLight position={[10, 10, 20]} angle={1} penumbra={0} />
            <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <Mesh />
            </Suspense>
       </Canvas>
    </div>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score -1):

After opening the modal, change the canvas size from javascript, when you do it from css you are only changing the visual size, for that reason it looks blurry

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(props.isOpen){
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext ("2d");

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; //change here to the size of the modal, you can calculate it or get it with a reference
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;//change here to the size of the modal, you can calculate it or get it with a reference
  }
},[props.isOpen])
```

Comment: react-three-fiber is already taking care of the resizing so it will be resized by him. https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/630#discussioncomment-52951